# Find pointer to derived class in a table after the object was destroyed

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting

I have a `Derived` class derived from class `Base`

I have a std:: container of `Derived*` pointers (such as vector, set, etc...). I have a `Base*` pointer and I would like to know if the container contains that pointer.

RTTI and `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base)` are not usable at that point, as the object may have been already destroyed, or we may be in the Destructor call chain.

How can I check if the container contains the base pointer?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design to be honest.

Comment: @CoryKramer : this sounds like useless comment as you do not know the context (framework used, etc...)

Comment: @Rabbid76 : because I need to access the Derived objects. These are in fact QObjects subclasses (Qt) and I'm receiving "destroyed()" signals if you are familiar with Qt.

Comment: You're asking people for help, then criticizing them for not knowing details that you haven't provided. Don't do that. If your question isn't complete that's your fault, and you need to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `static_cast` works, then it is possible.

[Cppreference : static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) .

> If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, static_cast performs a downcast. Such static_cast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means, such as when implementing static polymorphism. Safe downcast may be done with dynamic_cast.

There are no checks, so static_cast should make the correct pointer adjustment.

`reinterpret_cast` relies on &base == &derived
`static_cast` allows compiler to return an adjustment to base if the derived class is not at start of the object.

Could you get the callback to occur earlier?

Comment: I have 100 ways to do it differently, yes. And I probably would. I would just like an answer to the question for knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I have finally used an earlier callback, a finished() signal instead of a destroyed() signal, the finished() signal triggering object destruction elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the base is not virutal, then `static_cast` from base to derived will probably work. Unfortunately, if the deleted object was of another derived type, then the cast itself has undefined behaviour according to the standard. Being very pedantic, the wording of the standard makes even the `static_cast` from a base pointer that points to the subobject of the now-deleted derived object of the correct type because, strictly speaking, the pointer no longer points to a subobject of anything. In practice though, I wouldn't expect any other than "works as expected" behaviour as long as the casted pointer is not dereferenced.

> If the object of type “cv1 B” is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

I recommend considering ways to prevent the situation happening. Sending the callback from or before the destructor, before the object is actually deleted would allow using `dynamic_cast`. Another option would be to store base pointers in the set. If you've encapsulated the set correctly (and the base is not virtual), then you can safely `static_cast` the pointer in the set into derived pointers.